# call action class in case of error result in struts2

Tags: struts2, struts-config

I have two actions one is for customer search and another is customer update. In customer search `customer` action is invoked and lands in `CustomerEdit.jsp` with pre populated values.

After changing the existing values i submit the form. If successfully submitted then it goes to `CustomerSuccess.jsp`.

But if in case of problem or error i need to show `CustomerEdit.jsp` with pre populated values. how can i achieve it.

```
    <action name="customer"
        class="net.test.action.CustomerAction">
        <result name="success">CustomerEdit.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">CustomerSearch.jsp</result>
</action>       
    <action name="customerUpdate"
        class="net.viralpatel.struts2.action.CustomerAction">
        <result name="success">CustomerSuccess.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">CustomerEdit.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Pre-populated with what? If your action has getters/setters for the form values, and the form has fields for those, they'll be filled.

Comment: form values need to be fetched from DB dynamically every time the page gets loaded.

Comment: So fetch them; what's the issue? That's what the `Preparable` interface is for.